# How to test code path for read-only file access with PHPunit

Tags: phpunit, readonly, file-access

I have a PHP application with a code path which is only triggered if a specified file is read-only. If the file is readable and writeable another code path is taken. In particular, I am struggling with `unlink`. The simplified code to be tested looks like this

```php
try {
  // do something
  unlink($pathToFile);
  // do more
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
  // recovery and alternative code if unlink failed
}
```

The catch-branch is taken, if `unlink` fails because the file is not writable. I have confirmed that manually by creating a read-only file.

My problem is to write a automated test with PHPunit which runs locally on my development machine in the checked out working directory but also as part of Github workflows.

I already tried to create a sample file with PHPunit and then `chmod` the file to `0666`. Unfortunately, this does not trigger the exception, because the file permission seem to be by-passed if the calling user is the owner of the file (which is somehow plausible). I also tried `chmod` inside PHPunit and make `0` (aka root) the owner of the file, but this fails, because a non-root user is not allowed to call `chmod`.

Anyway, what is the right approach to "loose" file access rights for the user who is executing the PHPunit process and who is running the PHP application? (Everything I tried so far seemed to be a dead-end as if it was impossible to get rid and throw away the rights on a file which one created oneself.)

Answer (score -1):

To make `unlink()` return false, unlink a file that does not exist at all.

Example code with single-line error handling (alternative to catch/try in your example which you can do as well):

```php
$result = @unlink('/path/to/non-existing-file');
if (false === $result) {
    # ...
}
```

And if you need to configure much more, an existing tool that allows more fine-grained control is [Vfs Stream](https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream). It even allows to create dedicated errors.

Comment: This answer does not help at all. The problem is not with this particular `unlink`, that was _only_  a _single_ example. Obviously, I should not have given an example. Moreover, my system-under-test chooses the filename, not my test code. So I really need to mimick a read-only file system somehow. _That_ was the question. However, I have already solved the problem. I just haven't had the time to write up the answer.

Comment: Okay, that was not clear to me from your question, and indeed this is a very limited answer to a very specific problem. If you need to do more, use a virtual file-system that allows fine-grained control.  For example vfs stream https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream